# What penances did Vishwamitra perform?

Tags: brahman, vishwamitra, tapasya

What penances of Vishwamitra  alarmed even the Devatas that elevated him to the status of BrahmRishi?

Comment: I remember reading it in the Matsya Purana, but I had to return the hard cover book back, and I can't find it anywhere online. If I remember correctly, Vasishtha owned the great cow who grants wishes, Kamdhenu, and Vasishtha had invited Kaushika (Vishwamitra) to eat. At the end of the meal, Kaushika wanted Kamdhenu, and Vasishtha refused. They later fought, using all types of astras, but Kaushika was defeated. Kaushika meditated for 1000 years without eating, and minimal breathing. During his meditation, Kaushika was hungry. 1/2

Comment: Kaushika decided to eat, but then, Indra in the form of a Brahmin testing Kaushika, asked Kaushika for food. Kaushika immediately gave it, and went back to meditation. After 1000 years, Kaushika's meditation was at peak energy. Brahma visited Kaushika, and granted him the term Brahmarishi, and bestowed knowledge of all celestial weapons to him. Brahma also named Kaushika as Vishwamitra, which means compassionate. Vishwamitra apologized to Vashishta, and they both became revered friends. 2/2

Comment: The coolest thing is, that Vishwamitra was actually a Kshastriya by birth. He was King Kaushika, and he ruled over the kingdom of Kanyakubja, which is now present-day Kannauj in Uttar Pradesh. This proves that a person of any caste can become a Brahmin or of another caste by bad deeds, good deeds, or penance.

Comment: Vishwamitra had obtained Brahminhoid by obtaining mantra-siddhi of Gayatri.